# symfony2 assetic dump stopped watch

Tags: symfony

I am doing a project in Symfony2 and I have a problem with assetics. I use to compress assetics yuicompressor but the command:

```
app/console assetic:dump --force --watch
```

does not work i get always this error after some time:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/optinet/vendor/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php on line 225
```

I've tried all the ways but not working always get the error.

thanks.

Comment: i tried sudo php -d memory_limit=600M app/console assetic:dump --force --watch but no working

Comment: whithout --watch work but i want with watch for when i edit code update asstics automatically. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to work around assetic in general with `assetic:dump --watch` like commands dig into [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) ! I moved there because of similar performance problems and lacking configuration options in assetic.

The watch command has the downside of only being able to run with debug option.

**Grunt/Guard** aka. **task watchers** are able to automatically re-dump **assets**, run **unit-tests** and **livereload** your browser on changes to controllers or assets.

- watch a quick [Guard introduction](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/guard-is-your-best-friend/) on nettuts to get an idea about how this works

They even provide nice integration for **GROWL** (OSX / Windows) and **libnotify** ( *nix ) notifications for completed/failed tasks.

Use one of these in combination with CoffeeScript,SASS,LESS, ... [source-maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/?redirect_from_locale=de) for **maximum frontend productivy**.

If you use Chrome and [Tincr](http://tin.cr/) with `assets:install web --symlink` you can even edit/debug your css and js **directly in DevTools** and save them back into your current bundle structure without leaving the browser.

Firefox has recently added source-map support in Aurora.

Assetic currently lacks the source-map options needed for various pre-processors but i'm working on that already ;-)