# How can I get livereload to work with symfony2 (using guard?)

Tags: symfony, guard, livereload

I have had livereload working with guard in my symfony site.  But my assets (css/js) were in the 'web' directory.  But then I learned that the best practice is to keep everything in 'src' so that you can keep all your files as a bundle.  So I moved it to the Resources/public directory in my bundle under my 'src' dir and ran:

```
php app/console assets:install target [--symlink]
```

This created the necessary symbolic links from 'web' to my 'src' assets, everything seems to work if I run guard in 'src/.../Resources/public', sass, compass, however live reload no longer works.  I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the symbolic links (it was working before, I'm using livereload.js) I've read here:

[symfony2 assetic dump stopped watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010548/symfony2-assetic-dump-stopped-watch)

and here:

[No route found for "GET /img/glyphicons-halflings.png"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128024/no-route-found-for-get-img-glyphicons-halflings-png)

that people have got livereload to work with symfony/guard/sass.  The trick, I assume is to write the Guardfile such that it runs the assets: install or assetic:dump, which I guess is what makes livereload work?  But I can't find anyone explaining how they got this set (symfony2, livereload, sass, guard) to work (maybe just the Guardfile?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle may be the better method. But all I ended up doing was downloading liveload.js from their site, adding it a javascript include, added this to my Guardfile:

```
guard 'livereload' do
 watch(%r{.+\.(css|html|js)$})
end
```

and ran guard manually.

Answer (score 5):

There is a bundle for live reloading assets: http://bundles.kunstmaan.be/news/automatically-refresh-your-browser-on-changes

Comment: This method uses grunt. It's similar to guard. It's a taskrunner that runs tasks on watched files but in JavaScript. JavaScript is a lighter dependency than ruby so perhaps it's an option for you. All the bundle does by the way is inject the LiveReload snippet where needed. The documentation also details how to use grunt.

Comment: Link is now 404 but found the actual bundle https://github.com/Kunstmaan/KunstmaanLiveReloadBundle